# Any easier way to get the first item in a list that matches a function, and return the item, and the list without that item?

Tags: elixir

Example: We have a list `[1,2,3,4]`, and a fn `&(&1 >= 3)` I want to get back the `3`, and `[1,2,4]`

Currently I'm doing it like:

```
index = Enum.find_index(list, func)
elem = Enum.at(list, index)
rest = List.delete_at(list, index)
```

This is 3 lines of code that seem like a common pattern that can be done shorter. Is there a better way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish the task as it is stated (split to the first occurrence only) use a sledgehammer that always works: [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce_while/3).

```rb
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]

input
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.reduce_while({nil, []}, fn {e, idx}, {value, rest} ->
  if e >= 3,
      do: {:halt, {e, Enum.reverse(rest) ++ tl(Enum.slice(input, idx..-1))}},
    else: {:cont, {value, [e | rest]}} end)
#⇒ {3, [1, 2, 4]}
```

The `with_index` trick is needed here for performance only. Once the element is found, we want to stop iterations immediately, hence we need the index of the next element to bulk-add the tail to the result.

---

Another way round would be to use [`Enum.split_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#split_while/2)

```rb
with {h, [e | t]} <- Enum.split_while(input, fn x -> not(x >= 3) end),
  do: {e, h ++ t}
#⇒ {3, [1, 2, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is exactly one element matching your function you could use `split_with` + pattern matching:

```
iex(1)> {[item], rest} = Enum.split_with([1,2,3,4], & &1 == 3)
{[3], [1, 2, 4]}
iex(2)> item
3
iex(3)> rest
[1, 2, 4]
```

Of course, this will crash if there are more than 1 match in the list. If you want to only extract the first one you could `{[item | _], rest}` but this will still remove all of them from `rest`, so I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are ultimately interested in is the list *without* the matching element, why not use `Enum.filter`.

```
Enum.filter(list, fn x -> x !== 3)
```

Just a side note, your initial anon function fn `&(&1 >= 3)` would match both 3 and 4, not just 3.